# Segmentation fault: 11 c++ when using vector

Tags: c++, vector, operating-system, segmentation-fault, project

i am trying to write a program for my university project the program is supposed to do *first come first serve* scheduling i have thought a lot about this function but i don't know how to make it work, i always get **Segmentation fault: 11**, i also tried to use **temp.at(j)** but it gave me **Segmentation fault: 6**, and i tried to minimise the vector so it would be in-bound by declaring the vectors outside the function, then use **temp.size()** instead of **Processes** but it also did't work.

```
void FCFS(Process ProcessDetails[], int Processes)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    vector<int> temp1;
    int first = 0; //first value to compare with.
    for(int j = 0; j < Processes; j++){ // to make sure that it passes through all elements.
        for(int i = 0; i < Processes; i++){ // pass each PID and Burst time to vector temp and temp1.
            if(ProcessDetails[i].ArrivalTime == first){
                temp.operator[](j) = ProcessDetails[i].PID;
                temp1.operator[](j) = ProcessDetails[i].BurstTime;
            }
        }
        first++;// increase first value to declare the round is finished and start a new one.
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < Processes; i++){ // pass the sorted vector values back to the arrays.
        ProcessDetails[i].PID = temp.operator[](i);
        ProcessDetails[i].BurstTime = temp1.operator[](i);
    }
}
```

the program works fine until it reaches this function, please help.

Comment: `temp.operator[](j)` is just `temp[j]`...

Comment: @milleniumbug thanks for clarifying that i was just afraid of using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of a vector's `operator[]()` is undefined if it is used to access elements that do not exist.

Since you have used default-constructed vectors, their size is zero - so they have no elements to access.

If you use the `.at()` member function, it will check the index and throw an exception (of type `std::out_of_range`, which is declared in the standard header `<stdexcept>`) when indices are invalid.  You can confirm that by wrapping the code in an appropriate `try`/`catch` block.

To eliminate the problem, you need to reize the vector (e.g. add elements to it using `push_back()`, resize it using `resize()`, etc) before using `operator[]()`.   And ensure the index is valid, since `operator[]()` does not resize a `std::vector`.

Also, `temp[j]` is equivalent to `temp.operator[](j)`.   For types that supply an `operator[]()` function, the compiler handles turning expressions like `temp[j]` into a call of `temp.operator[](j)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your vectors have no elements.

Using the vector operator[] will therefore fail.

Use push_back, emplace, resize, or [some other function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to add elements to the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to change your vector assignment to

```
       if(ProcessDetails[i].ArrivalTime == first){
            temp.push_back(ProcessDetails[i].PID);
            temp1.push_back(ProcessDetails[i].BurstTime);
        }
```